# Animating a Clock with Core Animation/CALayers

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, nsdate, calayer

I have a UIViewControler with 4 layers.

1. Face Plate of a Watch/Clock
2. Second Hand
3. Minute Hand
4. Hour Hand

I've gotten each hand to start moving onload at the correct time (by defining angles on a circle based on the time the app-loads).

How do I correctly define the motion and duration of motion (should be ad infinitum) using the `CABasicAnimation` accessor methods?

For instance, I've set my secondHandMotion (which is an instantiated CABasicAnimation object) to being at an angle on the clock frame that corresponds to current time:

```
CABasicAnimation *secondHandMotion = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
secondHandMotion.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sAlpha];
secondHandMotion.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2*M_PI)];
[secondHand addAnimation:secondHandMotion forKey:@"transform"];
```

where `sAlpha` is the angle as a function of time. 
The `secondHandMotion.toValue` statement is wrong, I know that. How do I tell it to keep moving, and at the correct interval, 1-second ticks?

Thanks!

Comment: Alright, so if I add: `secondHandMotion.duration = 60.0`, I get that it the secondHand makes a full loop in 60 seconds, but then it stops, since I don't know how to have it keep going (forever) after a 2-pi loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I implemented this in one of my apps I started from this tutorial

<strike>[Analog Clock using Quartz Core](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/03/analog-clock-using-quartz-core.html)</strike> <sub>broken link</sub>

[See Source on Github instead.](https://github.com/akdsouza/PSAnalogClock)

It recalculates every second which may give slightly more accurate results relating to the system clock.

The way I implemented the rotation was something like this (this is the animation part you still need the angle calculations you have done previously).

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

self.hourView.transform   = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, hourAngle);
self.minView.transform    = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, minutesAngle);
self.secondView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, secondsAngle);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

NOTE: I wrote this very early on in my iOS learning so it may be a bit horrible.

Comment: Yup, that's what I used, too to get the idea on how to get angles from clock motion. The problem now is animating png files. I have them moving, but only for 2-pi loops, and not at the correct rotational speeds.

Comment: Sorry I just found the tutorial I forgot it didn't rotate images. See my edited answer.

Comment: This, coupled with similar advice from a friend, fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you completely solved this issue but I have created a sample project that has a class where you can just pass it in some images and it will take care of the rest. https://github.com/paulio87/PSAnalogClock

Comment: I did solve this problem doing the exact same thing you did :)
Thanks for the response!

Comment: The correct link to Pauls project page now is https://github.com/akdsouza/PSAnalogClock

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PSAnalogClockView](https://github.com/akdsouza/PSAnalogClock). It nicely solves your problem in a reusable way.